# Consume Java web services from .Net

Tags: java, .net, web-services

I would like to know if it is possible to consume a Java web service using .NET (doesn't matter which version) and any sources to documentation for this.

Google has not helped me and I have had trouble finding anything from MSDN/Technet about this.

Thanks

Comment: I've never used it, but I believe this is exactly what WCF was made for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the Java web service uses standards such as WSDL, you should be able to add a service reference to it in .NET.  That's not to say that there wouldn't be quirks you might have to look out for, but you should have interoperability.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386382.aspx) shows you how to add a service reference in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Thanks - What kind of quirks do you refer to?

Comment: I haven't done web server interoperation between Java and .NET myself, but I have between PHP and .NET, ActionScript and .NET, etc.  The main problems I've encountered is that sometimes "primitive" type mapping might not occur exactly as you'd expect.